# sql query for select first word of data from column

Tags: sql-server, postgresql, sql-server-2008

I have a table with this data:

```
shyam banarjee
rahul khanna
priya kumari 
rohit srivastava
```

I just want first names, like this:

```
shyam
rahul
priya
rohit
```

Comment: Postgres or SQL Server? Those are two very different database products.

Answer (score 2):

You can use "Substrig" and "charindex" functions to get what you want.

See this code as a demo on how to use it:

```
declare @name varchar(30)
set @name = 'shyam banarjee'
select SUBSTRING(@name,1,charindex(' ',@name)-1)
```

In your case, instead of being a variable in the select, it will be your column name.

You could also look at "computed column" if ever you want to have a new column that would only contains the firstname.

Comment: Make sure to add a trailing space to handle names like `Prince` and `Madonna`.

Answer (score 1):

This will allow you to choose which part by simply filtering on RowNum.  It will work no matter how many values you have...(assuming data is in a table called #temp)

```
SELECT 
FIELD1,Value,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY FIELD1 ORDER BY FIELD1) RowNum
FROM 
#Temp T
CROSS APPLY STRING_SPLIT(FIELD1, ' ') T1
```

Specifically, this query will give you the first names.  If you want last name, change it to RowNum=2 on last line.

```
SELECT Value FROM
(
SELECT 
        FIELD1,
        Value,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY FIELD1 ORDER BY FIELD1) RowNum
    FROM 
        #Temp T
        CROSS APPLY STRING_SPLIT(FIELD1, ' ') T1
)
a 
WHERE RowNum=1
```

[`STRING_SPLIT` documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-split-transact-sql)

Answer (score 0):

In Postgres you can use `split_part()`

```
split_part(the_column, ' ', 1);
```

Or, if you need to deal with multiple spaces, you can use `regexp_split_to_array()`

```
(regexp_split_to_array(the_column, '\s+'))[1]
```

Answer (score 0):

```sql
select substr(columnname,1,instr(columnname,' ')) from tablename;
```

Comment: Hi Alina, its best to explain the answer, so that it is obvious to all future visitors.